# Alterar tamanho dos icones da NavigationView

Tags: android

[image: Tamanho que eu quero]

[image: Tamanho que está]

Não consigo aumentar o tamanho desses ícones... passei 1 dia inteiro pesquisando de tudo na net... livro em casa tbem e nada gostaria de saber se tem possibilidade de alterar o mesmo... se tiver alguém q possa explicar a onde...
Caso seja através de código favor explicar ainda sou novo no assunto rsrs
A imagem "igreja jacarepagua" tem o tamanho dos icones q gostaria q ficasse a imagem abaixo é a do meu desenvolvimento...
Obs: Criei aquele Navigation Drawer Activity

activity_main.xml >>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />
```

activity_main2_drawer.xml >>>>>

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">


<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_test"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/tod"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/teste"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/outro"
        android:icon="@drawable/layout_butao"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment_returned_black_24dp"
        android:title="Share"

        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:icon="@drawable/camada"
        android:title="Send" />


</group>
```

app_bar_main2.xml>>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main2" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    />
```

Comment: Leia isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/132 - Sem ao menos parte do seu código, fica difícil de ajudar.

Comment: Problema é simples na imagem abaixo o icone está menor q a imagem de cima...
quero aumentar  o icone da NavigationView...

Comment: Coloca uma imagem de tamanho maior

Comment: @Paiva já testei isso é claro mas obrigado